# Two arrays in one array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have one question: How can I push two arrays into one array, so scheme should look like:

```
array1 = array("element1", element2, "element3");
array2 = array("element4", element5, "element6");

[0] => FinalArray
        (
            [0] => array1[] => 
                      (
                            [0] = element1
                            [1] = element2
                            [2] = element3
                      )
            [1] => array2[] =>
                      (
                            [0] = element4
                            [1] = element5
                            [2] = element6
                      )
        )
```

I tried use array_push() or array_merge() but without success.

Thanks for hints.

Marek

Comment: `$FinalArray = array($array1, $array2);`

Comment: Try this `[$array1, $array2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all create the array

`$superArray = array();`

then add your arrays in the array

`$superArray[] = $array1;`

`$superArray[] = $array2;`

And you should be ok ;)

Hope this helped,

Comment: The answer with superArray was super helpfull :) I dont understand how I cannot do it -_- Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

Try below method.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("element1", element2, "element3");
$array2 = array("element4", element5, "element6");

$finalArray =  array($array1,$array2);
print_r($finalArray);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => element1
            [1] => element2
            [2] => element3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => element4
            [1] => element5
            [2] => element6
        )

)
```

Check code and result in link: **[Answer](https://eval.in/551152)**

Answer (score 2):

Try with

**METHOD 1**

```
$final = array("finalArray"=>array($array1,$array2));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [finalArray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => element1
                    [1] => element2
                    [2] => element3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => element4
                    [1] => element5
                    [2] => element6
                )

        )

)
```

**METHOD 2**

```
$final = array_merge(array($array1),array($array2));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => element1
            [1] => element2
            [2] => element3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => element4
            [1] => element5
            [2] => element6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$finalArray = [$array1, $array2];`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a [multi-dimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101) and is explained in the PHP documentation. You create an array and then set the values of that array to be arrays as well. You can go as deep as you need, the only limit is the available RAM. To create a multidimensional array you set your key and then another array as the value, such as this example:

```
$finalArray = array(
    0 => array (
        0 => "element1",
        1 => "element2",
        2 => "element3"
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => "element4",
        1 => "element5",
        2 => "element6"
    ),
);
```

Of course the keys are entirely optional in that example, I included them for clarity.

You can create the child arrays as separate variables first if you wish. For example:

```
$array1 = array (
    0 => "element1",
    1 => "element2",
    2 => "element3"
);
$array2 = array (
    0 => "element4",
    1 => "element5",
    2 => "element6"
);
$finalArray = array(
    $array1,
    $array2
);
```

I've done an [eval.in example](https://eval.in/551169) so you can see that they both output the same results.